# Azure migrate from GTE CyberTrust Global Root to the Baltimore CyberTrust Root

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure, I am running one web-application (ASP.Net, 4.0, C#) using SQL AZURE as database on one small instance of VM cloud service, I am also use Azure blob storage to save my files & images, I want to know how this migration will affect my application, what precautions I have to made so my application will not down after this migration.

Comment: Have you tried reading through http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/03/19/windows-azure-root-certificate-migration-impact-scenarios.aspx ? I'm pretty sure the answer to your questions are buried in Kevin's Q&A section.